# Windows: org not exporting pdf

Tags: org-mode, org-export, auctex, pdf

I am trying to get emacs org-mode to export to pdf. To this end I've installed tex-live and added the path to the bin folder to my emacs path. I've added the tex-live folder to my OS $PATH. When I try to export to pdf I get the following ouput:

```
(2)/research_plan/research_plan.tex
Processing LaTeX file research_plan.tex...
org-compile-file: File "c:/Users/Terry/tmar080@aucklanduni.ac.nz/Phd_git (2)/research_plan/research_plan.pdf" wasn’t produced.  See "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" for details
```

Where do I see *Org PDF LAtex Ouput*?
Ps I've also tried the following to no avail: 
Shown below is my init.el file:

```
;;(require 'package)
;;(package-initialize)
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(require 'cask "~/.emacs.d/.cask/cask.el")
(cask-initialize) 

;; BACKING UP
(setq make-backup-files nil) ;;no ~files
(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; start in scratch
(setq auto-save_default nil) ;; no more #files 

;;UI SPECIFIC FEATURES
(desktop-save-mode 1) ;; save workspace between sessions 
(tool-bar-mode -1) ;; no toolbars on top
(scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; no scrollbars
(global-visual-line-mode t);;line wrapping by word
(show-paren-mode t) ;; show matching bracket
(delete-selection-mode t) ;; overwrite selected text on type
(blink-cursor-mode -1) ;;cursor not blinking
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p) ;; yes or no is now y or n
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) ;; autoindent tabs

;;flx ido-mode
(require 'flx-ido)
(ido-mode 1)
(ido-everywhere 1)
(flx-ido-mode 1)
;; disable ido faces tqo see flx highlights.
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-use-faces nil)

;;Save cursor position in file
(require 'saveplace)
(setq save-place-file (concat user-emacs-directory "saveplace.el"))
(setq-default save-place t)

;;projectile
(projectile-global-mode t) 

;;autocomplete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default) 

;;font and theme
(set-frame-font "Source Code Pro for Powerline-14")
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (sanityinc-tomorrow-eighties)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("628278136f88aa1a151bb2d6c8a86bf2b7631fbea5f0f76cba2a0079cd910f7d" default)))
 '(flx-ido-threshold 10000)
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (auto-complete flx-ido color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; cygwin bash from within emacs
;; Let's use CYGWIN bash...
;;
(setq binary-process-input t) 
(setq w32-quote-process-args ?\") 
(setq shell-file-name "c:/cygwin64/bin/bash") ;; or sh if you rename your bash executable to sh. 
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name) 
(setq explicit-shell-file-name shell-file-name) 
(setenv "PATH"
    (concat "~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/texlive/2018/bin/win32:"
        (replace-regexp-in-string " " "\\\\ "
            (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "/"
                (replace-regexp-in-string "\\([A-Za-z]\\):" "/\\1"
                                          (getenv "PATH"))))))

(require 'shell-here)
(define-key (current-global-map) "\C-c!" 'shell-here)

;;(require 'package)
;;(package-initialize)
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(require 'cask "~/.emacs.d/.cask/cask.el")
(cask-initialize) 

;; BACKING UP
(setq make-backup-file nil) ;;no ~files
(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; start in scratch
(setq auto-save_default nil) ;; no more #files 

;;UI SPECIFIC FEATURES
(tool-bar-mode -1) ;; no toolbars on top
(scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; no scrollbars
(global-visual-line-mode t);;line wrapping by word
(show-paren-mode t) ;; show matching bracket
(delete-selection-mode t) ;; overwrite selected text on type
(blink-cursor-mode -1) ;;cursor not blinking
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p) ;; yes or no is now y or n
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) ;; autoindent tabs

;;flx ido-mode
(require 'flx-ido)
(ido-mode 1)
(ido-everywhere 1)
(flx-ido-mode 1)
;; disable ido faces tqo see flx highlights.
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-use-faces nil)

;;Save cursor position in file
(require 'saveplace)
(setq save-place-file (concat user-emacs-directory "saveplace.el"))
(setq-default save-place t)

;;projectile
(projectile-global-mode t) 

;;autocomplete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default) 

;;font and theme
(set-frame-font "Source Code Pro for Powerline-14")

(setq Tex-PDF-mode t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following: Export to LaTeX only and run the resulting LaTeX-file manually through pdflatex by running `pdflatex <filename>.tex` Then check the file `<filename>.log` for any errors. You are on Windows, so you installed TeX from the official distribution (which is good, TeX Live on Unix/Linux gets sometimes mixed up with Linux-distribution-specific TeX distributions).

Comment: Running pdflatex revealed that a lot of packages were missing from my cygwin texlive distro so I installed the texlive windows version and added it to my emacs path and ran pdflatex from the windows texlive bin folder and it worked. Thank you so much!!!